# Is there a way to deliver a customized file to a server via puppet

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I have several machines I am managing via puppet. The machines are at different physical locations.  Each location has a specific location number.

I have a config file that needs to have the correct location number in it.

So the contents of /etc/abc.conf are like this:

```
this=that
location=$LOCATION_NUMBER
bananas=tasty
```

When the file gets pushed down to the machine, I need $LOCATION_NUMBER to actually be the location number.

Can I manage this file with puppet and how?

If I export a facter for LOCATION_NUMBER, can puppet write the correct location number when it pushes the file down to the machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're looking to do is called a template.  It's a core feature of Puppet, and very useful.  You write a file in eRB format that can use Ruby code and Facter variables to build a file.  Here's an example:

```
file { '/etc/my_config_file':
  ensure => present,
  owner => 'root',
  group => 'root',
  mode => 0700,
  content => template('module/my_config_file.erb'),
}
```

Now, in your module hierarchy under `templates/` (**not** `files/`), place a file `my_config_file.erb`:

```
this=that
location=<%= LOCATION_NUMBER %>
bananas=tasty
```

The `<%= %>` format says to execute some Ruby code and return the result.  In this case, all facts are available as local variables, like `ipaddress`, `lsbmajdistrelease` or `LOCATION_NUMBER`(your custom fact).  You can also use any other Ruby code that doesn't directly return a result inside `<% %>`, such as `if` statements:

```
<% if LOCATION_NUMBER == 7 %>
custom_config=true
<% else %>
custom_config=false
<% end %>
```

**Edit**: As I re-read this answer, I'd like to suggest that you don't use capital letters for your Fact name.  In Ruby, a variable that starts with a capital letter is immutable.  While I'm not sure this is *really* an issue, it goes against convention.

Comment: I'll have to do some research into templates, but this is just what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can store the $LOCATION_NUMBER variable as a parameter to be returned by a [ENC](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/external_nodes.html) . You use the ENC so that hosts in a particular location( or domain), or group or hostname, get a particular variable. There are several good, free ENCs pre-built and available, including Dashboard and The Foreman.